# How to test a Fragment with a ViewModel scoped in a graph

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I´m using the `navGraphViewModels` ViewModel scoping on Android, and when I´m implementing the Fragment tests I can´t even start the test.
I´m using mockito to mock the `NavigationController` and using the [documentation suggested aproach](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing#kotlin) with the `fragmentScenario`. The problem comes when the ViewModel is tryed to be created that throws an Exception because `NavController#getBackStackEntry` is not mocked and I can´t mock it because `NavController` is a final class.

How can I test that uses ViewModels which are scoped to a navigation graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of time I found the answer.

You should change the fragment `NavController` by one that you have created and changed it `ViewModelStore`. An example of this is found in the [test](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/navigation/navigation-fragment-ktx/src/androidTest/java/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavGraphViewModelLazyTest.kt?source=post_page---------------------------%2F&autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F#59) of the Android Source code.

```
val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<TestVMFragment>()
    navController.setViewModelStore(ViewModelStore())
    scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
    }
}
```